# Why is my const declaration failing to assign a hex value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to declare a constant value for a hexdecimal value but it seems I can't achieve this in C#.

```
const PROCESSES = &H1F0FFF;
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: a simple google search could have yielded you the correct answer.. just sayin

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
const int PROCESSES = 0x1F0FFF;
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you why H is missing?

Comment: @Marius Since it is VB convention for hex numbers.

Comment: @Marius Main problem in missed constant type.

Comment: see VB.NET vs. C# http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html